# How do I handle possible null values in TypeScript when I can't access the defintions

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm writing a React App with TypeScript, and using Firebase, and I have a couple of errors which are similar.

I've written my Firebase class:

```
class Firebase {

  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);
  }

  // *** Auth API ***
  doSignInWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) => app.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  
  doEmailUpdate = (email:string) => app.auth().currentUser.updateEmail(email)
  
  doPasswordUpdate = (password:string) => app.auth().currentUser.updatePassword(password)

  doPasswordReset = (email:string) => app.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email)

  doSignOut = () => app.auth().signOut();

  getUserIdToken = () => app.auth().currentUser.getIdToken();

}
 
export default Firebase;
```

**Problem 1:** `doEmailUpdate` and `doPasswordUpdate`are both highlighted with the error "Object is possibly null".  This is because `app.auth().currentUser` is null if the user isn't signed in.  I can get around this by using `app.auth().currentUser?` and making sure it's only called if the user is signed in, but is there a better way?  I tried doing

```
if(app.auth().currentUser !== null) ...
```

but still got the error.

**Problem 2:** `getUserIdToken` also highlights that `app.auth().currentUser` may be null, but again I can get around that using `app.auth().currentUser?.  However, I'm calling this in a component using:

```
const MyComponent= ({ firebase}) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    
    (firebase.getUserIdToken())
      .then((token:string) => { ... })
  })

})
```

and I get the error `Object is possibly 'undefined'.`  This is because the return type of getUserIdToken is `Promise<string> | undefined`

Obviously I can't change the return type of a Firebase function, so how do I get around this?

Comment: Please consider modifying the code here to constitute a [mcve] suitable for dropping into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/Gm30LW) which demonstrates your issue and only your issue (so any undeclared or unimported things should be fixed).  This will help folks who want to answer start from your problem and work on a solution, instead of having to spend time first working to reproduce your problem.

Comment: In general the answer here is going to look like "if you're calling a function that returns a possibly-nullish thing, don't call that function multiple times.  The compiler has no idea that subsequent calls to the function will return the same result.  Instead, hold onto its return value and check it for null before you use it."  I'd be able to write out [explicit versions of this](https://tsplay.dev/KwXo8W), but without a [mcve] I can drop into an IDE, I have no idea if it will have its own errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Promise.reject()` if `app.auth().currentUser` is `undefined || null`, that way you're returning a `Promise<string | undefined>` as opposed to `Promise<string> | undefined`.

I'd refactor `getUserIdToken` to look like this

```js
getUserIdToken = () => {
  if (app.auth().currentUser) {
    return app.auth().currentUser.getIdToken()
  }
  return Promise.reject();
};
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  Is there a similar solution for the first issue I'm having?

Comment: The same approach should still work, return a Promise object if there's no `app.auth().currentUser`